# using nested attributes in rails with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have this setup and for some reason, I can't save the employent_history in the database. when the updated only the profile attributes are updated i used cocoon gem

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :employent_histories :through :profile
  after_create :init_profile

  def init_profile
    self.create_profile!
  end
end
```

As you can see the profile is created when a new user is created

I added another model called employment_history that belong to but user and profile

The Profile Model 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :employment_history

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :employent_histories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employent_histories
end

class EmploymentHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :profile

 end
```

profile_controller.rb

There is no create action because the resource is created when a new user is ctreated

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end


  def edit
      @profile = current_user.profile
  end


    def update
    # byebug
      @profile = current_user.profile
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update profile_params
        format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path, notice: "Profile updated!" }
        format.json { render :edit, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_profile_path, flash: { error: "Profile could not be updated!" } }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors.messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:title,:phone,:address,:zip_code,employment_histories:[:job_title,:employer,:_destroy])
  end
```

views/profiles/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
   <%= attributes%>
   <%= attributes%>
     <%= f.fields_for :employment_histories do |ff| %>
      <%= attributes%>
     <%end%>
<%f.sumbit%>
<%end%>
```

Using this setup , the fields for the nested attributes form does not display on the edit profile page. 
what am i missing

Comment: You code has many syntax errors and a bad formatting. Can you fix those?

Comment: If you _"want to add the nested_attributes params to the profile creation"_, why not do `self.create_profile!(employment_histories_attributes: [{ <obj1-attributes> }, { <obj2-attributes> }])`?

Comment: Where do you get the values of these attributes?

Comment: i edited the question because i ran in an issue with the nested form

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the employement_history is not saved in the database, i can't figure out why

Comment: Can you show the complete `update` action as well as the server logs for update request?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh i just updated the full update action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are permitting `:employment_histories` in the params, but AFAIR, the nested params are supposed to be received under key `:<association-name>_attributes`.

Also, you should permit the `id` of nested objects, in case you want to edit them again.

So, the final `profile_params` should look like:

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile)
        .permit(
          :title,
          :phone,
          :address,
          :zip_code,
          employment_histories_attributes: [:id, :job_title, :employer, :_destroy]
        )
end
```